# FullCalendar trying to fetch events from URL instead of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, fullcalendar, sails.js

Using FullCalendar v3.9.0 with jQuery v3.3.1. I have a SailsJS application that's getting the calendar data from MySQL.

this.me.calendar from MySQL currently looks like this.

```
[{"start":"2018-07-04T13:30:00","end":"2018-07-04T18:00:00","works":["2"]}]
```

And my FullCalendar code looks like this.

```
let that = this;
that.me.calendar = this.me.calendar;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'today prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  views: {
    week: {
      titleFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    }
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  locale: 'fi',
  weekends: false,
  scrollTime: '07:00',
  businessHours: {
    start: '7:00',
    end: '21:00',
  },
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    let events = that.me.calendar ? that.me.calendar : [];
    console.log(events);
    callback(events);
  },
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  select: (start, end) => {
    let duration = (end - start) / 1000;
    if (duration == 1800) {
      // Set default duration to 1 hour
      end = start.add(30, 'mins');
      return $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select', start, end);
    }

    let eventData = {
      start: start,
      end: end,
      works: []
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
  },
  eventClick: (event, element) => {
    $('#event-works').text(event.works.join(','));
    $('#start-date').text(moment(event.start).format('d.MM.YYYY HH:mm'));
    $('#end-date').text(moment(event.end).format('d.MM.YYYY HH:mm'));
    $('#workModal').modal('show');

    $('#add-work-to-event').click(() => {
      let work = $('#work').val();
      if(_.includes(event.works, work)) return;
      event.works.push(work);
      $('#event-works').text(event.works.join(','));
    });
  }
});
```

While the code above doesn't send the `GET`, it doesn't display the events in the calendar. However, if I change the events to `events: this.me.calendar`, the SailsJS console displays `GET /account/%22[%7B/%22start/%22:/%222018-07-04T13:30:00/%22,/%22end/%22:/%222018-07-04T18:00:00/%22,/%22works/%22:[/%222/%22]%7D]%22  (1ms 404)`.

I also tried changing it to `events: JSON.stringify(this.me.calendar)`, which still gave the GET request in console.

If I enter the array in the events on it's own, it is working. Also the console.log inside the events function is returning the same array.

Is there a way for me to simply enter my array for FullCalendar, or do I have to make it get the JSON from an URL?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by changing the `let events` inside of my events function to `let events = that.me.calendar ? JSON.parse(that.me.calendar) : [];` and now the events are being displayed.

Comment: To clarify for others, this will be because `that.me.calendar` is a string containing some JSON data, not a URL. However without the code above parsing it from JSON into a JS array, fullCalendar doesn't know it's supposed to be data, so it assumes it's meant to be a URL (or part of a URL) and tries to make a HTTP request to it and get the data from there.